# Adding view controller .h and .m?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

This may sound like a noob question but when I add a view controller to my storyboard how do I create a new .h and .m for that controller and connect them to it?

Sorry I'm new at this.

I appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways

Either File->New->'New File' or right click in the group you want to put your view controller and choose 'New File'

You get a popup for filetype - the type you want is 'Objective-c class'

The next screen shows a space for your class name (i.e. MyNewViewController) and the type of object you want it to inherit from. In your case that's `UIViewController`

Hope that helps.